# Elasticsearch getting count of distinct rows

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

I need to find the count of distinct field IDs using `elasticsearch`

My data format is

```
{
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "16bcd4dc080f4c789018dd97f76741ef",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "jinu",
               "team_id": "500"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "9ed8afe738aa63c28b66994cef1f83c6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "lal",
               "team_id": "500"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1d238cd2f8c06790fc20859a16e3183b",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "author1",
               "team_id": "500"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "616ee1c00a02564f71bb6c3067054d55",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "kannan",
               "team_id": "400"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "d48132bfaed792f3c32d12e310d41c87",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "author3",
               "team_id": "400"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1a9d05586a8dc3f29b4c8147997391f9",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "dibish",
               "team_id": "100"
            }
         }

      ]
   }
```

Here there are three distinct `team_id`s: `500, 400, 100`. In this case I want to get the count as 3. I have tried cardinality aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "team_id_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "team_id"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here am getting the correct result but I can see that `elasticsearch` documentation states that cardinality is an *experimental feature* and it may be subject to change in future.

Is there any way to achieve this without using cardinality aggregation? Is there any problem to use this experimental cardinality function? Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/outboxprov1/user/_search -d '
{
  "size": 0,
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "team_id_count" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "team_id"
            }
        }
    }

}'
```

Comment: I have tried terms aggregation earlier but am not getting the exact count here. Response like the following way 
"buckets": [
            {
               "key": "500",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "400",
               "doc_count": 2
            }]

Comment: Hmm. After indexing your documents, I am getting correct results. Does your index have a mapping ? My result: {
    "team_id_count": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "500",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "400",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "100",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Am also getting the same result. But i need to get the count as 3, ie 3 distinct ids are there (500, 400, 100)

Comment: I think I got you wrong. I don't know the future of "cardinality aggregation" but as an alternative you could calculate the"buckets" length after getting "terms aggregation"